# In Objective-C and Cocoa, is there a function debug_print(foobar) that will print out variable's name as well as dumping out it value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For example:

```
debug_print(foobar);     // prints out:  foobar is (hello, world)
debug_print(i * 27);     // prints out:  i * 27 is 54
```

in other words, print out the variable or the expression literally first, and then dump its values out.

It doesn't need to be in this form.  It can be called as a string too:

```
debug_print("foobar");     // prints out:  foobar is (hello, world)
debug_print("i * 27");     // prints out:  i * 27 is 54
```

**Update: or how can it be written if it is not built in?**

Comment: You could conceivably create such a macro, using Objective-C's introspection facilities, but I don't believe there's anything "canned".  (Actually, it probably wouldn't need introspection, just a bit of macro magic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the macro

```
#define debug_print(expr...) NSLog(@"%@ is %@", @#expr, (expr))
```

As you can see, the NSLog format string expects a %@ (object), so you need to use a variant for integers:

```
#define debug_printI(expr...) NSLog(@"%@ is %d", @#expr, (expr))
```

**EDIT:**

There is a way to use a single macro and have it work with all types: use @encoding to find the type.

```
NSString *print_debug_format_for_type(const char *encoding) {
switch (encoding[0]) {
    case '@': return @"%@ is %@";
    case '*': return @"%@ is %s";

    case 'f': return @"%@ is %f";
    case 'd': return @"%@ is %f";

    case 'q': return @"%@ is %qi";
    case 'Q': return @"%@ is %qu";

    case 'c':
    case 'i':
    case 's':
    default: return @"%@ is %d";
}
}

#define debug_print(expr...) ({                                 \
typedef __typeof__(expr) t;                                     \
NSLog(print_debug_format_for_type(@encode(t)), @#expr, (expr)); \
})
```

With this, you can use debug_print anywhere with (almost) any type, as long as it's in the print_debug_format_for_type.  The encodings that are passed in (from @encode) can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) [apple docs], and the formats for the format string can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) [also apple docs].  As is, this works with any object, c-style string, integer, float, or double expression.

(minor caveat: the ObjC BOOL type is actually a typedef'd char, so if you print_debug a boolean expression it will say it is a 1 or 0.  While this works, it also means that if you print_debug a char expression, it will say it is the ascii number of the char.  To change this behavior (and break BOOL printing), change case 'c' to `return @"%@ is %c"`.

Comment: If I may toot my own horn a bit, a more general implementation (which supports aggregate types) can be found here: http://jens.ayton.se/blag/almost-elegant-cave-man-debugging/ It’s a bit of a Swiss Army sledge hammer, but convenient at times.

Comment: @Jared if it involves a function, then it cannot be put into a `.h` file and get included by *two* or more files that use this marco, because multiple definition of function will exist... I try moving the function to a `debugp.m` and the macro to `debugp.h` and let `debugp.m` have the line `#import "debug.h"` but it doesn't work... do you know how?

Comment: Yup, you'll need to move the function into a file in order to include use the macro in more than one file.  (Alternatively you can declare the function as static, but don't do that.)  Can you tell me what the error is now, with the function in another file?  I have the feeling you didn't declare the function prototype around the macro.  It would be `NSString *print_debug_format_for_type(const char *encoding);`, preferably before the #define.  The whole function would still need to be in the debugp.m as well.

Comment: wow yes, it is the prototype... you are a Genius!  I tried earlier to make that into an Objective Class `DebugP`, and have `debugp` macro invoke the class method of the class DebugP... but it didn't like the `@` I think, because the compiler thought that was a selector...

Comment: Is it possible to make it work automatically for `CGPoint` as well?  But is it complicated, since there are so many other structs, such as `CGSize`, `CGRect`

Comment: The easy answer is to use the NSStringFrom* family of functions [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW34].  Eg: debug_print(NSStringFromCGPoint(mypoint))

Comment: looks like it is treating `double` as integer... I tried `double c = 1.23;` and then `debugp(c)` and it prints an integer.  If I `NSLog(@"%s", encoding);`, it shows it is `d` as well

Comment: oh by the way, using the NSStringFrom is fine... just that it is not automatic... I'd imagine if Apple has a more capable NSLog function, that'd be quite handy

Comment: looks like `d` is for `double`... so maybe it is a `%lf`?

Comment: also, `debugp("hello")` will show an encoding of `[6c]`... don't know if that is the same if you try it

Comment: I made a typo (case 'd': return @"%@ is %d" -> case 'd': return @"%@ is %f") and edited it. Thanks for catching it! I wouldn't really use debugp with c-string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do what you want in a completely general sense in Objective-C, because any mechanism for printing a value needs to know the type of that value.  For expressions that definitely be object pointers, you could do something like this:

```
#define debug_print(expr) NSLog(@"%@ is %@", @#expr, (expr))
```

In Objective-C++, you could use templates to make a completely general solution, such as:

```
#define debug_print(expr) do { std::cerr << #expr << " is " << (expr) } while (false)
```

Using a preprocessor and the "stringify" operator ("#") is how you take the text that's in the parentheses and print it.

Comment: True. I've edited it, which makes that part redundant with your answer.